# foreach every 3 put inside a new ul

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

Actually I have this foreach loop:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ( $tasks as $task ) { ?>
        <li>
            ...
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

It returns:

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Now I need to change the loop to put every 3 `<li>` into a new `<ul>`, so I can have:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    ...
</div>
```

How I have to modify the foreach loop to achieve that result?

Comment: Extra `ul` for what? If it is design issue then use css `column-count`

Comment: Have you tried something? it isn't that hard, simple if sentence a' counter and perhaps a reset?

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

Just [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) your array into chunks of 3 and then [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) each subArray, e.g.

```
<div>
    <?php

    foreach (array_chunk($tasks, 3) as $task) {
        echo "<ul><li>" . implode("</li><li>", $task) . "</li></ul>";
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
foreach (array_chunk($arrays, 3, true) as $array)
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($array as $value)
    {
         echo "<li>".$value."</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ( $tasks as $k=>$task ) { ?>

         <?php if($k % 3 == 1) { ?>
         <ul>
         <?php } ?>
        <li></li>
         <?php if($k % 3 == 0) { ?>
         </ul>
         <?php } ?> 
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I like @Rizer123's answer for conciceness, but if you wish to keep iterating over the individual items, rather than chunking (for example; if you need to perform some manipulation on the individual items) I'd suggest something like the following:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ( array_values($tasks) as $k => $task ) { 
        if($k % 3 == 0) { ?>
        <ul>
        <?php } ?>
        <li>
            ...
        </li>
        if($k % 3 == 2) { ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$k` represents the key (or 'index') of each element of the array, which in this code snippet will be reset (by use of array_values) to a consecutive series of integers starting at `0`